# unmodified vector - always empty

Tags: c++, vector

When I go to the function "nieuwe bestelling", which allows me to fill the vector. Afterwards I print the vector with the function toevoegen but it is still empty.

-- I am using eclipse luna

MAIN

```
int main(void)
{
tafel tafelObj;
short choice;


                    cout<<(" 1. nieuwe bestelling\n 2. tafel instellingen);
                    cin>>choice;

                    switch(choice)
                    {
                        case(1): cout<<"nieuwe bestelling"<<endl;
                        tafelObj.nieuwebestelling();
                        break;
                        case(2): cout<<"tafel instellingen"<<endl;
                        tafelObj.toevoegen();
                        break;
                    }
  }
```

.
/*
* tafel.cpp
*  Created on: 18 Jul 2014
*      Author: alex
*/

```
#include "../tafel.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

tafel::tafel() {
    //constr
}

void tafel::nieuwebestelling()
{
        std::string besteld;
        static int tafelnummer=1;

        while(besteld!= "end")
        {
            std::cout<<"bestelling: ";
            std::getline (std::cin,besteld);
            bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.push_back(besteld);
        }
        std::cout<<"---------------------------"<<std::endl;
}
void tafel::toevoegen()
{

    int tafelnummer=1;
    std::cout<<"----------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"gewijzigd"<<std::endl;

    for(unsigned int i =0; i< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"i";
        std::cout<< bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"eind"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>tafelnummer; //This is just here so I can clearly see, the point where everything should be printed
}
```

.

```
/*
 * tafel.h
 *
 *  Created on: 18 Jul 2014
 *      Author: alex
 */

#ifndef TAFEL_H_
#define TAFEL_H_

#define tafels 10

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


class tafel {
public:
    static int i;
    struct bestelling  //elke tafel heeft een struct waarin alle gerechten enzo in staan. ide struct = ide tafel
    {
        std::vector<std::string>gerechten;
    }bestellingen[tafels];

    tafel();
    void nieuwebestelling();
    void toevoegen();
};


#endif /* TAFEL_H_ */
```

Comment: You have an array of vectors...why not make it a vector of vectors? Or at least an array of arrays. Or something consistent! Also, please give us your `main`

Comment: @Josh i used a struct because afterwards i might add other information in the struct, it will be more than just that vector

Comment: @Jacques I understand, but either use all vectors in your code, or use all arrays. Mixing them is not good practice. Why not have a vector of the sturcts?

Comment: Oooh ok yes I got it! Thanks I will do this, having vector of structs will be way better for later in my program. So I will be able to modify the size of that new vector. thx

Comment: @Josh ,I tried what you told me but I am always getting a problem. My problem crashes each time, I ve tried to debug it in several ways but I dont know why it crashes when I use vectors. Do you please have any idea?
code: http://ideone.com/4LrQUb

Comment: Well seeing as the file is called 'main.java' I'd guess you forgot to select c++

Comment: @Josh i suppose this is a mistake i made when uploading the code on that platform. I have this problem when I compile and run it with eclipse (luna)

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to duplicate the problem you are describing with the following `main`:

```
int main()
{
   tafel t;
   t.nieuwebestelling();
   t.toevoegen();
   return 0;
}
```

However, I am going to point out a bug in your code. In the following `while` loop,

```
    while(besteld!= "end")
    {
        std::cout<<"bestelling: ";
        std::getline (std::cin,besteld);
        bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.push_back(besteld);
    }
```

the string `"end"` will be added to `bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten` since you are checking the value of `besteld` after it has been added to `bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten`.

You can change that block of code to:

```
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<"bestelling: ";
        std::getline (std::cin,besteld);
        if ( besteld == "end" )
        {
           break;
        }
        bestellingen[tafelnummer].gerechten.push_back(besteld);
    }
```

to remove that bug.

Comment: so u mean: first you go to "nieuwe bestelling" and fill the vector. afterwards you print the vector and it shows you what you typed previously? O.o
Thx i will correct that as well

Comment: @R Sahu really very strange when i do it, using eclipse lune. The vector always appears as empty altough i fill it with stuff...
thanks though

Comment: @JaqcuesMartin, you should add that additional info about using eclipse to your post. Somebody with experience in eclipse might know problems related to eclipse.

Comment: @R Sahu oh ok, do you really think some compilers might create problems for that kind of "basic" stuff?

Comment: @JaqcuesMartin, my suspicion is that it is related to the run time environment and how `stdin` is handled in the run time environment.